# PowerShell - Check if user has folder access through a security group

Tags: powershell

I was able to check through this code, but it is showing the permissions of all subfolders, I would like it to show only the current path, how to adjust this code in this way?

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

```
$User = "domain\user"
$UserOhneDomain = "user"
$Path = "folderpath"
$List = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserOhneDomain 

$GroupArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
$GroupArrayList.Add($Group.Name) | Out-Null
} 

# Fields we want in list, an array of calculated properties.
$OutputFields = @(
    @{name="Item" ;       expression={$_.Path.split(':',3)[-1]}}
    @{name="Rights" ;     expression={$Right.FileSystemRights}}
    @{name="AccessType" ; expression={$Right.AccessControlType}}
#    @{name="User" ;       expression={$User}}
) 
$FileSystemObjects = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName}

foreach ($Item in $FileSystemObjects) {
    foreach ($Right in $Item.Access) {
        if ($Right.IdentityReference -eq $User)
        {
            $List.Add(($Item | Select-Object $OutputFields))
        }
    }   
}


foreach ($Item in $FileSystemObjects) {
    foreach ($Right in $Item.Access) {
        foreach ($GroupArrayItem in $GroupArrayList){
            if ($Right.IdentityReference -eq ("domain\" + $GroupArrayItem)) 
            {
                $List.Add(($Item | Select-Object $OutputFields))
            }
        }
    }   
}

$List | Out-File C:\Users\user\Desktop\PermissionCheck.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the "*-Recurse*" parameter in the following line:

```
$FileSystemObjects = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName}
```

I don't have a AD to check now, but i think that is the problem here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
Removing "-Recurse" worked in parts, now it does not show all subfolders, but it is still showing 1 level after the current folder.

Example: \\server\share\folder\subfolder1\subfolder2

folder: \\server\share\folder\ (shows the permissions of: \\server\share\folder\subfolder1), I would like it to show only the permissions of: \\server\share\folder
Any other ideas?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

Get-Item -LiteralPath $Path | where-object {($_.PsIsContainer -eq $true)}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).